# How to create name of data table using Textbox

Tags: c#

can you help me with this sql command

```
 CON.Open();
      SqlCommand comand =new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE Dobavljaci +textBox2.Text(ID int,Naziv Char(50),Sjediste Char(50),Adresa Char (50),Ziroracun Char (50),sifra Char(50),JIB Char(50);",CON);

      comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 CON.Close();
```

and how to use later one "SELECT" "INSERT" using textbox.text

Additional
I try like this

```
 CON.Open();
  SqlCommand comand =new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE"+textBox2.Text+"(ID int,Naziv Char(50),Sjediste Char(50),Adresa Char (50),Ziroracun Char (50),sifra Char(50),JIB Char(50);",CON);

          comand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 CON.Close();
```

But how to add additional name or text with textbox.text

Comment: In your code the name of the text box appears as a literal into the string. You need to concatenate strings, something like "CREATE TABLE " + TextBox2.Text + "(ID int,Naziv Char(50),Sjediste Char(50),Adresa...." However it's better idea to use parameters for preventing SQL injection.

Comment: I get this error 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text' cannot be used like a method.And i need to use additional name with  textbox2.text

Comment: This is because you have Text() in your code. Remove parenthesis. Text isn't a method but a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
SqlCommand comand =new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE Dobavljaci" + textBox2.Text + "(ID int,Naziv Char(50),Sjediste Char(50),Adresa Char (50),Ziroracun Char (50),sifra Char(50),JIB Char(50));",CON);
```